# What attributes do I need to push and pop in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, visualization

Here is a case, I want to do like that..

```
void func()
{
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_FOG);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_1D);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
        glDepthRange (0.0, 0.999);
        glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
        glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        glLineWidth(1.0f);

        glPushMatrix();
        {
            glTranslatef(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
            glRotatef(angle.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glRotatef(angle.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            glRotatef(angle.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            draw();

        }
        glPopMatrix();
  }
```

I am pushing these atributes, but not sure, so just wanna know what attributes are OK with this function.

```
    glPushAttrib(GL_LINE_BIT | GL_TRANSFORM_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT | GL_LIGHTING_BIT | GL_CURRENT_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

func();

    glPopAttrib();
```

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushAttrib.xml, this is a list of parameters that can be passed to that function and the corresponding saved state. As a sidenote keep in mind that state changes are expensive so try to group things that share the same state.

Comment: In modern times, there's probably no measurable penalty for throwing caution to the wind and using `GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS`. Many years ago, there were limits to the size of the state stack and it'd be useful to push the minimum set of states. However, since modern OpenGL (core profiles) are designed not to even have a state stack, trying to be efficient when using this legacy feature is probably counter-productive in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page that Maurice linked in the comment above (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushAttrib.xml) should get you a long way, and is the easiest source. Unfortunately the man pages tend to have errors and omissions, and are therefore generally not very reliable.

If you want to go to the definitive source, the spec documents are your friends. For example, download the OpenGL 4.5 Compatibility Profile spec from https://www.opengl.org/registry/. You will need the Compatibility Profile version, because the attribute stack functionality is deprecated and not available in the Core Profile.

Then, if you didn't fall off your chair after opening the almost 1000 page PDF file, you will find a complete set of state tables in chapter 23, starting on page 697.

Now, let's pick the first call from your list to illustrate how you extract the information you're looking for:

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

After some searching, we land in table 23.26 "Pixel Operations". The second row from the bottom says `DEPTH_TEST` in the first column. In the last column (Attribute), it says "depth-buffer/enable". This tells us which attribute group(s) the attribute belongs to. In this case it's two of them.

From there, we go to table 21.4 "Attribute Groups" on page 677. This table lists how the attribute groups translate to the `_BIT` constants. For our example, we find:

- depth-buffer: `DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`
- enable: `ENABLE_BIT`

Note that the spec document leaves out the `GL_` prefix.

So for the depth test enable state, both `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` and `GL_ENABLE_BIT` will save the state when used as argument to `glPushAttrib()`.

All that's left now if for you to look up the other pieces of state the same way, and you have the authoritative answer.

Comment: Thanks, its really helps, So, I would need GL_ENABLE_BIT for every case, because there are so many times we need to enable and disable something.